# Ayuda a solucionar un problema con mi código JavaScrip (Cannot read property 'style')

Tags: javascript

Saludos estoy creando una sección de Registro de pago donde el usuario luego que escoja el plan que mas le guste pueda seleccionar los días y horarios que mas les convengan, de inicio quiero ocultar las opciones de días y horarios ya que me hacen el formulario muy extenso pero luego que el usuario elija un plan se le despliegue mediante un `style.display = 'block'`; el contenido pero me da este error:

```
Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLInputElement.mostrarDias.
```

Acá les dejo el código con el que estoy trabajando. De antemano agradecido por cualquier opinión u ayuda.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    //campos Datos usuarios
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
    var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    //Campos planes y paquetes principiantes
    var uno_princ = document.getElementById('uno_princ');
    var cuatro_princ = document.getElementById('cuatro_princ');
    var ocho_princ = document.getElementById('ocho_princ');
    var doce_princ = document.getElementById('doce_princ');
    //Campos planes y paquetes intermedios
    var uno_inter = document.getElementById('uno_inter');
    var cuatro_inter = document.getElementById('cuatro_inter');
    var ocho_inter = document.getElementById('ocho_inter');
    var doce_inter = document.getElementById('doce_inter');
    //botones y divs 
    var calcular = document.getElementById('calcular');
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    var botonRegistro = document.getElementById('btnRegistro');
    var lista_productos = document.getElementById('lista-productos');
    var suma = document.getElementById('suma-total');

    calcular.addEventListener('click', calcularMontos);

    uno_princ.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    cuatro_princ.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    ocho_princ.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    doce_princ.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    uno_inter.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    cuatro_inter.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    ocho_inter.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);
    doce_inter.addEventListener('blur', mostrarDias);

    function calcularMontos() {
      event.preventDefault();

      var unaclaseprinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        cuatroclaseprinc = parseInt(cuatro_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        ochoclaseprinc = parseInt(ocho_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        doceclaseprinc = parseInt(doce_princ.value, 10) || 0,

        unaclaseinter = parseInt(uno_inter.value, 10) || 0,
        cuatroclaseinter = parseInt(cuatro_inter.value, 10) || 0,
        ochoclaseinter = parseInt(ocho_inter.value, 10) || 0,
        doceclaseinter = parseInt(doce_inter.value, 10) || 0;


      var totalPagar = (unaclaseprinc * 7) + (cuatroclaseprinc * 22) + (ochoclaseprinc * 65) + (doceclaseprinc * 75) + (unaclaseinter * 10) +
        (cuatroclaseinter * 33) + (ochoclaseinter * 75) + (doceclaseinter * 95);


      var listadoProductos = [];


      if (unaclaseprinc >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push('Plan: ' + unaclaseprinc + ' Clase de Yoga Principiante');
      }
      if (cuatroclaseprinc >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(cuatroclaseprinc + ' Paquete: de (4) Clases de Yoga Principiante');
      }
      if (ochoclaseprinc >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(ochoclaseprinc + ' Paquete: de (8) Clases de Yoga Principiante');
      }
      if (doceclaseprinc >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(doceclaseprinc + ' Paquete: de (12) Clases de Yoga Principiante');
      }
      if (unaclaseinter >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push('Plan: ' + unaclaseinter + ' Clase de Yoga Intermedio');
      }
      if (cuatroclaseinter >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(cuatroclaseinter + ' Paquete: de (4) Clases de Yoga Intermedio');
      }
      if (ochoclaseinter >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(ochoclaseinter + ' Paquete: de (8) Clases de Yoga Intermedio');
      }
      if (doceclaseinter >= 1) {
        listadoProductos.push(doceclaseinter + ' Paquete: de (12) Clases de Yoga Intermedio');
      }
      lista_productos.style.display = "block";
      lista_productos.innerHTML = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < listadoProductos.length; i++) {
        lista_productos.innerHTML += listadoProductos[i] + '<br/>';
      }
      suma.innerHTML = "S/ " + totalPagar.toFixed(2);

    }

    function mostrarDias() {
      var lunesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        martesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        miercolesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
        juevesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0;
      var horaElegidas = [];
      if (martesPrinc > 0) {
        horaElegidas.push('lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles', 'jueves');
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < horaElegidas.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(horaElegidas[i]).style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  }); // DOMContentLoaded
})();
```

```html
<div id="eventos" class="eventos clearfix">
  <h3>horarios de preferencia</h3>
  <div class="caja">
    <div id="lunes" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
      <h4>Lunes</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Principiantes:</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_01" value="taller_01"><time>8:00am a 9:00am</time></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--#Lunes-->
    <div id="martes" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
      <h4>Martes</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Principiantes:</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_02" value="taller_02"><time>6:00am a 7:00am</time> </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_03" value="taller_03"><time>7:00am a 8:00am</time> </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_04" value="taller_04"><time>8:00am a 9:00am</time> </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--#martes-->
    <div id="Miercoles" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
      <h4>Miércoles</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Principiantes:</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_05" value="taller_05"><time>8:00am a 9:00am</time></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--#miercoles-->
    <div id="jueves" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
      <h4>Jueves</h4>
      <div>
        <p>Principiantes:</p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_06" value="taller_06"><time>6:00am a 7:00am</time> </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_07" value="taller_07"><time>7:00am a 8:00am</time> </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_08" value="taller_08"><time>8:00am a 9:00am</time> </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--#jueves-->

  </div>
  <!--.caja-->
</div>
<!--#eventos-->
```

Comment: puedes colocar tambien el html ?

Comment: Saludos bienvenido, agrega tu codigo HTML para entender un poco mas tu problema y darte mejores posibles soluciones [edit]

Comment: Disculpen soy nuevo publicando acá en stackoverflow, ya le agregue el codigo HTML

Answer (score 1):

Da Null a `document.getElementById(horaElegidas[i])` lo que significa es que estas ejecutando esa sentencia antes de que se cargue el dom

Deberias ejecutar la funcion una vez que se cargue, ya sea dentro del evento load.

```
   <script>
    function mostrarDias(){
    var lunesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
    martesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value,10) || 0,
    miercolesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0,
    juevesPrinc = parseInt(uno_princ.value, 10) || 0;

    var horaElegidas = [];
    if (martesPrinc > 0) {
        horaElegidas.push('lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles', 'jueves');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < horaElegidas.length; i++) {                
        document.getElementById(horaElegidas[i]).style.display='block'; 
    }
}
      window.onload = function() {
  yourFunction(param1, param2);
};
    </script>
```

O poniendo tu js luego de tu html

Ademas de esto en tu Array estas pasando un ID que no existe,

```
  horaElegidas.push('lunes', 'martes', 'miercoles', 'jueves');
```

id "miercoles" y en tu html

```
 <div id="Miercoles" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
```

Comment: Saludos las funciones las estoy ejecutando luego que se cargue el DOM quisiera mostrar el código completo pero no se como hacerlo cuando trato de insertarlo me dice que tengo mucho código, solo pude publicar extractos del código a ver si se lograba entender mi problema

Comment: Como mencione en la respuesta, cambia el ID del html "Miercoles"

Comment: Dios Gracias Luciano, ya me esta corriendo, el error era el ID="Miercoles" , ya tenia horas y no lograba visualizarlo. Muchas gracias